# Cannot load external URL using a simple jQuery dataTables

Tags: jquery, html, json, datatables

I created a simple static web project in Eclipse. I downloaded jquery.js and jquery.dataTables.js into my WebContent folder. Then I created a index.html page which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource" : 'http://localhost:8080/myProj/listLogs?messageId=33333333333'
        });
    });
</script>


<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"
        id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>stuff</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>stuff</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

The JSON response from http://localhost:8080/myProj/listLogs?messageId=33333333333 should look like:

{

```
"aaData": [
    [
        "This is a NEW message"
    ],
    [
        "Parsing message with messageId = 33333333333 and eventType = CREATE"
    ],
    [
        "Start running workflow with 4 actions"
    ],
    [
        "Updating entitlement for event: [33333333333:CREATE]"
    ],
```

...
}

But when I open the index.html in my firefox, nothing gets loaded. I do see this on the page though:

```
stuff
stuff
Loading...
Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries
PreviousNext
```

My JSON URL was not even invoked. Not sure why.

Comment: validate your json using http://JSONLint.com it is not valid

Comment: Just did. It is valid. As I said, the URL is not even invoked. I can tell by monitoring on the server side.

Comment: i will advise you to please have a look in the firebug console or XHR request from XHR tab under net panel of firefox to see if your URL invocation caused some error like 500 internal server error or 404 error that will help you and also check if the pat is correct

Comment: On a side note, with jQuery you no longer need `$(document).ready(function() {`. Just simplly enclose onload code in: `$(function(){ //code goes here });`

Comment: firebug console says: GET http://localhost:8080/myProj/listLogs?messageId=33333333333&_=1328766548589 200 OK x 254ms. Hum...seems that the URL did get invoked correctly. Still nothing shows up on the page.

Comment: Also, I tried downloading the returned JSON response to a .txt file and loading it by "sAjaxSource" : 'json.txt'. This works.

Comment: BTW, everything works when I open the page in my Eclipse web browser, but not in firefox.

Comment: Deploying to a server does NOT work either. Only when opening the html file in the Eclipse browser works.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the answer:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

My JSON endpoint is on a different port :)